# "is not running" and "stop/waiting" - what's the difference?

Tags: 14.04, services

Why does these 2 return different output, although they're both services?

```
$ sudo service cassandra status
 * Cassandra is not running

$ sudo service mongod status
mongod stop/waiting


$ service --status-all
 [ - ]  cassandra
 [ + ]  mongod
```

And why does the 3rd output says `mongod` is actually running (`[ + ]`)?

Comment: The first indicates a sysv init script (`/etc/init.d/cassandra`), the second indicates an Upstart job (`/etc/init/mongod.conf`). Dunno about the third. Possibly a bug, or `mongod` is not using Upstart, but init.